# Jersey Exception : A message body reader for Java class and MIME media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded was not found

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Jersey based Rest WS which outputs JSON. I am implementing a HttpClient to invoke the WS and consume the JSON response. The client code I have is below

```
public static String sendPostRequest(String url, String accept,
        String authorization, Map<String, String> body)
        throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException {

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    if (authorization != null && !authorization.equals("")) {
        post.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authorization);
        // post.setHeader("access_token", authorization);
    }

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> map : body.entrySet()) {
        String key = map.getKey();
        String value = map.getValue();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
    }

    UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
            urlParameters);
    post.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("Response Code : "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println("JSON : " + json);
    return json;
}
```

I am sending the access token as header. I get the proper response if I use curl command for this `curl -X POST http://192.168.33.70:8080/management/orgs/org1/apps?access_token=YWMtXh3LwK4XEeWaSPc_E_-PwQAAAVIRV758KgNhJ-y3wNNAx5MLSmwTQvi1OPg -d '{"name":"app1"}'`, but through `HttpClient` I get the following exception stacktrace :

```
2015-12-29 12:49:18 ERROR          rest.exceptions.AbstractExceptionMapper.toResponse(72)<http-bio-8080-exec-5>- javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException Server Error (500)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body reader for Java class java.util.Map, and Java type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>, and MIME media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded was not found.

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:477)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:927)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:875)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.usergrid.rest.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body reader for Java class java.util.Map, and Java type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>, and MIME media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded was not found.
```

I have the correct MIME TYPES in my request. My POJO has been annotated with XMLRootElement. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You realize that in your cURL request, the default content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but the data you trying to send is in JSON format. I don't see how that could possible work. Show your resource method.

Comment: Its working for all other requests for which access token is not required, I've declared the "@Produces( {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/javascript", "application/x-javascript", "text/ecmascript",
        "application/ecmascript", "text/jscript"
} )" in my rest controller.

Comment: The error is for reading the request entity. `@Produces` has nothing to do with that. It's `@Consumes` that is for the request entity type. Post your server code for more help.

Comment: Ok, I've checked on HttpClient api there is no direct method to send content type. So how to get rid of this thing?

Comment: How can I send content type in HttpClient, do you have any idea?

Comment: Thanks, something is happening :P

Comment: You add content-type in request header. Besides I do not think that is your problem here. Please see my answer.

Comment: When I am hitting the same request from postman adding header (token), content type as well as accept. It will giving me the exact response I am looking for.

Comment: I will do that Himanshu Please give me some time.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body reader for Java class java.util.Map, and Java type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>, and MIME media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded was not found.
```

As the exception message suggests you are trying to Marshall/Unmarshall Map data type to JSON which is not supported by default in Jersey as the marshalling/unmarshalling of object is handled by JAXB which does not support maps. However the implementation can be overriden with GSON by google to register MessageBodyReader/Writer. A simple implementation of using GSON with Jersey can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/hstaudacher/4967804). Apart from that there are many implementations of GSON with Jersey available on internet.

What I am more interested in is the code of **UrlEncodedFormEntity** class. Please post it for more insight.